# Entity Framework Code First MySQL Linked Table

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have a Property table and I have a Property Ratios table.

Properties may or may not have Ratio data.

I am attempting to create a link between the 2 tables but I am getting the error when trying to do an "add-migration".

These are my tables:

```
public class PropertyForSale
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Index("IX_pid", IsClustered = false, IsUnique = true, Order = 1), MaxLength(15)]
    public string pid { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(25)]
    public string Status { get; set; }

    public virtual PropertyRatios PropertyRatios { get; set; }
}

public class PropertyRatios
{
    [Key, MaxLength(15)]
    public string pid { get; set; }

    public float Zest_List_Price_Diff { get; set; }

    [Index]
    public DateTime LastUpdated { get; set; }

}
```

And here is my fluent API configuration:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<PropertyForSale>()
            .HasOptional(o => o.PropertyRatios)
            .WithOptionalPrincipal()
            .Map(o => o.MapKey("pid"));
```

I am getting the error:

> One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:
>   pid: Name: Each property name in a type must be unique. Property name 'pid' is already defined.

I want the tables linked via the "pid".

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Remove `public string pid { get; set; }` from `PropertyForSale`
Renaming parameters just to make it more readable.

`AddMigration` will do this for you

```
public class PropertyForSale
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(25)]
    public string Status { get; set; }

    public virtual PropertyRatios PropertyRatios { get; set; }
}

public class PropertyRatios
{
    [Key, MaxLength(15)]
    public string pid { get; set; }

    public float Zest_List_Price_Diff { get; set; }

    [Index]
    public DateTime LastUpdated { get; set; }

}
```

This will create `pid` as foreign key in `PropertyForSale`.

Comment: that causes an additional column to be added to my Property table called "PropertyRatiosID". I don't want an additional column?

Comment: Its not an additional property , I just made it mode readable . and removed `PID`

Comment: I am not allowed to change the shape of the property table. Only add a foreign key to the existing "pid" column